# How to optionally pass a logger to a Symfony Bundle

Tags: symfony, logging

I'd like to make the end developer able to optionally pass a `logger` to the bundle I'm developing.

How can I make this optional?

Currently I've set the configuration in `Resources/config/services.xml` like this:

```
    <service id="stripe_bundle.manager.stripe_api" class="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\StripeBundle\Service\StripeManager">
        <argument>%stripe_bundle.stripe.secret_key%</argument>
        <argument>%stripe_bundle.kernel_environment%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
        <argument type="service" id="stripe_bundle.syncer.charge" />
        <argument type="service" id="stripe_bundle.syncer.customer" />
        <argument type="service" id="stripe_bundle.syncer.webhook_event" />
    </service>
```

As you can see, I've set an "hard" dependency on the service with id `logger`. But it may happen this service doesn't exist, or it has another name.

How can I make the developer able to set this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
<argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null" />
```

Documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/optional_dependencies.html